# Magento 2: How to get specific product attribute on the product page?

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.1.6, product-page

I need to display a specific product attribute value.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write below code in phtml file.

```
<?php
    echo $_product->getData('perverpakking');
?>
```

If it is dropdown attribute, then use below code.

```
<?php
    echo $_product->getAttributeText('perverpakking');
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting now some value out of it, but not the right value. screenshot: https://ibb.co/jdhBQF

Comment: Is it dropdown attribute ? If yes then see my updated answer to print dropdown attribute value.